# Big query update or delete issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I can't do any update or delete operation by big query api via php. Have any techniques to complete this task.

Answer (score 3):

2016-08: BigQuery support for UPDATE and DELETE :)

[Does BigQuery support UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT (SQL DML) statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922795/does-bigquery-support-update-delete-and-insert-sql-dml-statements)

---

You can achieve UPDATEs and DELETEs with BigQuery - it's just not a native operation.

To delete rows from a table, re-materialize without the un-desired rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM [my.table1]
WHERE NOT id IN (19239,192392139,129391)
```

(set as options "allow large results" and "write results to my.table1")

To update rows, you can do something similar:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM [my.table1]
  WHERE NOT id IN (SELECT id FROM [my.updated_rows]
), (
  SELECT * FROM [my.updated_rows]
)
```

In other words: BigQuery is an analytical database, where DELETE and UPDATE are not optimized operations - but you pull them off with a single SELECT statement that overwrites the original table.

Comment: Thank a lot for ur response. Now i delete any row by web UI but i can't that by api. My platform is php. Please help me. My sample code is there

Comment: My code is : 
$destinationTable = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableReference(); $destinationTable->setDatasetId(''); $destinationTable->setProjectId(''); $destinationTable->setTableId(''); $queryConfig = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationQuery(); $queryConfig->setDestinationTable($destinationTable); Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationLoad(); $queryConfig->setWriteDisposition("WRITE_TRUNCATE"); $sql = "select * from [] where not ( id = 4 )"; $queryResults = $myBigQueryObject->requestBigQuery($sql);
After run this code [id=>4] not overwrite or deleted from my table

Comment: Can you start a new question? PHP is not my strength, but someone else could help

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that BigQuery is a [WORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many) technology (append-only by design). It looks for me, that you are not aware of this thing, as there is no option like `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Comment: So how can i do my job for updating any row by big query? Is it only fetch or insert data?

Comment: There is no UPDATE call. You can add new rows, it's append-only technology and it's more like event based. You will end up with 10 rows and you need to write your queries in a way to extract the newest row. You cannot update an existing row, you need to insert a new one.

Comment: but you can always re-materialize tables https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/613313661776621568

Answer (score 1):

As other friends explained, BigQuery has append-only design.

Instead of deleting a row, you should write a sql query which filters all un-wanted rows from your table; and you should create a brand new table from the results of this query. Then you can delete the old table.

For updating, you should append new updated rows to the table, and follow the instructions i wrote above for removing the old rows.

Answer (score 0):

I have stopped setting write disposition and then could run dml statements on bigquery using python call

dont set following parameter

```
query_job_config.write_disposition
```