# Issues while implementing Google Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

Our company is going to implement Big Query.
We saw many drawbacks in Big Query like
1. Only 1000 requests per day allowed.
2. No update delete allowed.
and so on...

Can u guys highlight some more drawbacks and also discuss on above two.
Please share any issues come during and after implementing Big Query.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

> "Only 1000 requests per day allowed"

Not true, fortunately! There is a limit of how many batch loads you can do to a table per day (1000, so one every 90 seconds), but this is about loading data, not querying it. And if you need to load data more frequently, you can use the streaming API for up to a 100,000 rows per second per table.

> "No update delete allowed"

BigQuery is an analytical database which are not optimized for updates and deletes of individual rows. The analytical databases that support these operations usually do with caveats and performance costs. You can achieve the equivalent update and deletes with BigQuery by re-materializing your tables in just a couple minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663889/132438